# Can't get the printer to print a custom sized paper in C# Windows Form project

Tags: c#, printing

I've been recently trying to print a form in a C# application.Taking the form picture was easy, but I'm stuck in printing section. I've read so many articles and so many solutions to get a custom sized paper printed (I mean my form to be printed on a paper that I specify for the printer), but sadly none worked.

Here is what I have in my project so far :

```
//my method for taking a picture form the form , and then printing it .
void PrintImage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    int x = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.X;
    int y = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Y;
    int width = this.Width;
    int height = this.Height;

    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(width, height);

   // e.PageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("62mm", 244, (int)Size.Width) { RawKind = 259 };

    this.DrawToBitmap(img, bounds);
    Point p = new Point(0, 0);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, p);
}

//getting the list of installed printers .  
private void comboBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (string printer in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(printer);
    }
}




   //Print Button Click event declaration 
    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex !=-1)
        {
            pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("CardSize", 50, 50);
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintImage);
        pd.Print();

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok i found it out :
for making a custom paper size , one should just simply do :

```
          PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
          PaperSize paperSize = new PaperSize("MyCustomSize", 200, 200 ); //numbers are optional

           paperSize.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.Custom;

           pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
```